# BufferedReader loop in while

Tags: java, file, loops, bufferedreader

Here's my code. I'm trying to read this text file:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
```

In the code below, BufferedReader should stop at the line "DDD",  but program goes in loop.

I tried to replace "DDD" with null and it worked, but I want it stop at the line I specified!
I'm stucked in this issue and I don't know how to solve it... solution?

```
import java.io.*;

public class Reading{

public Reading() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        new Reading();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("test.txt")));
        String line;

        while((line = br.readLine()) != "DDD"){
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        br.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: do `while(!((line = br.readLine()).equals("DDD")))` instead. Don't compare Strings with `==` or `!=`

Comment: Oh my god thank you, i always forget String in not a primitive variable, thank you so much!